# Как сделать хорошую физику прыжка в юнити? (инерция)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать так, чтобы во время прыжка у игрока небыло свободного движения. То есть игрок например бежит, а потом на бегу прыгает то даже если не использовать кнопки передвижения он продолжит лететь со скоростью бега которая постепенно во время прыжка уменьшается. Одним словом инерция. Ни в ютубе ни в гугле хорошего ответа не нашел

Comment: Используй передвижение через физику и запрети реагировать на кнопки если персонаж не на земле. Все.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.